# State machine, what to use instead of enum to store multiple states eg ( 0% to 100% for a vehicle's drive base height)

Tags: c#, state-machine

```
enum RideHeight_State 
    {
        rideHeight = 100
    }
```

I'm trying to use rideHeight variable as if it is an int by calling:

```
RideHeight_State.rideHeight -= 10; // Decrement rideHeight State by 10
```

inside a private void function later on...

Any thoughts on where I'm going wrong?

Thank You

Comment: `rideHeight` isn't a variable, it's an enum value. You can't modify enum values at runtime.

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you want to change the value?

Comment: @mjwills, I'm trying to get the state of the drive base height of a vehicle (measured from 0% to 100%), This value changes every time a joystick button is pressed. Ultimately this is for packaging the states to send over to the onboard computer on the vehicle. If there needs to be more clarification please let me know.

Comment: Do that with an `int` not an enum.

Comment: Ah, so I could use an int for states as well? I always had the assumption that in state machines you needed to use struct, enums or switches for good practice etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may need to do this:

```
enum RideHeight_State
{
    rideHeight,
}

private Dictionary<RideHeight_State, int> _state = new Dictionary<RideHeight_State, int>()
{
    { RideHeight_State.rideHeight, 100 },
};
```

Then this code might work more like you expect:

```
_state[RideHeight_State.rideHeight] -= 10;

Console.WriteLine(_state[RideHeight_State.rideHeight]);
```

That outputs `90`.

Your naming convention for your `enum` is not very clear though. I wasn't sure what to suggest there.

Answer (score 1):

Enums are essentially related named constants. You can't change their values at runtime. If you want a state machine then use a class with static properties.